# Convert NSData to CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, avfoundation, nsdata, cmsamplebufferref

Is there any way to create CMSampleBufferRef from NSData? NSData object has also be constructed from CMSampleBufferRef formerly. I need that conversion because I want to save the  CMSampleBufferRef frames (as NSData) that are taken from live camera using AVFoundation, then be able to use the CMSampleBufferRef frames (by converting NSData objects to CMSampleBufferRef) to construct a video.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hey did you found the way around it? I am doing similar operation. Let me know kindly if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, i couldn't make it work ;(

Comment: Did you able to find a way to convert the CMSampleBuffer to NSData and NSData to CMSampleBuffer?

Comment: It was long time ago, unfortunately I don't remember clearly :( I guess I changed my implementation strategy.

Comment: @TechFlitter, did you manage to convert the data back to samplebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

```html
-(AudioBufferList *) getBufferListFromData: (NSData *) data
{
       if (data.length > 0)
       {
            NSUInteger len = [data length];
            //I guess you can use Byte*, void* or Float32*. I am not sure if that makes any difference.
            Byte * byteData = (Byte*) malloc (len);
            memcpy (byteData, [data bytes], len);
            if (byteData)
            {
                 AudioBufferList * theDataBuffer =(AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) * 1);
                 theDataBuffer->mNumberBuffers = 1;
                 theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = len;
                 theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
                 theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mData = byteData;
                 // Read the data into an AudioBufferList
                 return theDataBuffer;
             }
        }
        return nil;
}
```